# PHP Form inputting same Value for 2 fields which are different

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table which I want to be able to choose the Restaurant ID & Name and insert it into the new table for the deal which is linked to that restaurant.

```
<?php
// First we start a session which allow for us to store information as SESSION variables.
session_start();
// "require" creates an error message and stops the script. "include" creates an error and continues the script.
require "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Restaurants";
$result= mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $Restaurant_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['Restaurant_ID']);
    $Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['Name']);
}   

?>
<select name="Restaurant_ID">
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .=  '<option value ="'. $row['Restaurant_ID'] .'">'. $row['Name'] .'</option>';
    }

echo $output;
?>
</select>
</div> 
<select name="Name">
    <?php
    foreach($result1 as $row1)
    {
        $output .=  '<option '. $row1['Name'] .'>'. $row1['Name'] .'</option>';
    }
echo $output;
?>

</select>
```

when it puts them into the table it gives $Name & $Restaurant_ID the same name and inserts only $Restaurant_ID in both fields.

Site to see how it works http://thefoodieapp.co.uk/thefoodieappv1/deal_form.php?signup=success

[image: This is how it looks once inserted into the table]

Comment: You're skipping the first row of results because of `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`. The `for` loop won't use that row because it has already been fetched.

Comment: You never use `$Restaurant_ID` and `$Name` for anything.

Comment: The options in the `Name` dropdown are missing `value=`

Comment: Where do you set `$result1`?

Comment: @Barmar how do I fix this ?

Comment: Why do you need separate menus for name and ID? If you have a restaurant ID, you can get its name from the `Restaurants` table. The `Deals` table should just contain the ID, it shouldn't duplicate the name.

Comment: Fix it by not doing it.

Comment: Fixed gave output its only version output1 and that seems to have worked

Comment: @Barmar im super new and couldn't figure out how to get it to show the restaurant name for the deal in foreach I have running on this page

http://thefoodieapp.co.uk/thefoodieappv1/deals.php

Comment: You haven't shown the code that insert into the `Deals` table, so there's no way to know why it's inserting the wrong thing into the Name column. But the Deals table shouldn't have a Name column in the first place, it's a violation of database normalization.

Comment: The restaurant name already shows in the first dropdown: `'<option value ="'. $row['Restaurant_ID'] .'">'. $row['Name'] .'</option>';`